# Dificuldade em criar sessões para salvar dados de formulário

Tags: php

Tenho um formulário que tem 6 campos e um botão que permite ao usuário repetir estes 6 campos para adicionar mais dados.

Quero salvar os dados em uma sessão, e gravar no BD apenas quando o usuário finalizar o preenchimento.

Não estou sabendo criar as sessões direito, as pesquisas q fiz não ajudaram muito. Segue o código:

**novaRequisicao.php**

```
    $sql="SELECT COD_GRUPO, DES_GRUPO_PRODUTO FROM supervisor.GRUPO_PRODUTO";
$query= mssql_query($sql) or die ('Erro ao realizar consulta ao banco de dados');

?>

<script>
//Carrega a página com os produtos de acordo com o grupo escolhido
        $(document).ready(function(){
            $('#grupoProdutos').change(function(){
                $('#produtos').load('listaProdutos.php?grupoProdutos='+$('#grupoProdutos').val());
            });
        });

//função para adicionar mais produtos
$document.ready(function(){
    $("#add").click(function(){
        $("#clona").clone().appendTo("#aqui");
    });
});
</script>

<div class="grid_24 cinza subtitulo">Nova Requisição</div>
<!-- formulário para requisição de produtos  -->
<form action="novaRequisicao.php" method="POST">    
<div id="clona">
<div class="grid_7">
    Selecione um grupo de produtos<br>
    <select name="grupoProdutos[]" id="grupoProdutos" required="required">
        <option value=""> Selecione</option>
    <?php
        while($row=mssql_fetch_array($query)){
            $codGrupo=$row['COD_GRUPO'];
            $grupo=$row['DES_GRUPO_PRODUTO'];
            echo " <option value='".$codGrupo."'>".$grupo." </option> ";
        }
    ?>
    </select>
</div>
<div id="produtos" ></div>
<div id="aqui"></div>
```

**listaProdutos.php**

```
    <?php
require('includes/conect.php');

$grupoProdutos = $_GET['grupoProdutos'];
$sql=mssql_query("SELECT * FROM supervisor.PRODUTO WHERE COD_GRUPO='$grupoProdutos' ORDER BY DES_PRODUTO");
?>
<div class="grid_10">
<?php
echo "Selecione um produto<br> <select name='produto[]' required='required'>";
echo " <option value=''>Selecione</option> ";
while ($row=mssql_fetch_array($sql)) {
        $id=$row['COD_PRODUTO'];
        $nome=$row['DES_PRODUTO'];
    echo " <option value='$id'>".$nome."</option> ";
}
echo "</select>";

?>
<br><br>
Preencha se o produto não está na listagem<br> 
<input type="text" name="naoListado[]" class='largeInput' placeholder='Nome do produto não listado'>
</div>
<div class="grid_4">
Quantidade<br>
<input type="number" name="quantidade[]" required="required" class="shortInput" min="1">
<br><br>
Tipo<br>
<input type="text" name='tipo[]' placeholder='Kg, ml, etc.'>
</div>
<div class="grid_6">
Observações<br>
    <textarea  name="observacoes[]" cols="30" rows="5"></textarea>
</div>
<div class="grid_2">
<button id="add">+</button>
</div>
<div class="grid_2">
<input type="submit" value="Finalizar requisição" class="emerland text-white but">

</div>
```

Comment: É melhor editar a pergunta e incluir o que já tem feito.

Comment: @PapaCharlie, editei

Comment: mas no arquivo novaRequisicao.php os dados estão chegando certo? o problema é só para gravar esses dados na sessão? Se puder mandar o codigo do arquivo novaRequisicao.php

Comment: O código do arquivo novaRequisicao.php é este primeiro. Os dados estão chegando certo sim, só preciso gravar na sessão e depois do formulário finalizado, gravar no banco.

Comment: @AmandaLima e aonde esta o código da sua sessão?

Comment: @Gerep, este é o problema, nunca usei sessões e não sei nem como começo.

Comment: @AmandaLima, neste caso eu recomendo este link: http://blog.vilourenco.com.br/php-trabalhando-com-sessions/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para criar instâncias de uma sessão, primeiro deve-se inicializar uma sessão, nunca depois, ou retorna erro.

Inicializar uma sessão:

```
session_start();
```

A função deve estar sempre no início do código, nunca depois, porque é um *header*, e os *headers* devem ser sempre enviados antes de qualquer outra informação.

Para criar variáveis dessa mesma sessão, e assinar valores a elas, utilize a variável `$_SESSION['indice_da_sessao']`, veja:

```
$_SESSION['meu_nome'] = "Edilson";
// Ou ainda
$meu_nome = "Edilson";
$meu_codigo = 123;
$_SESSION['meu_nome'] = $meu_nome;
$_SESSION['meu_codigo'] = $meu_codigo;
```

Depois de usar estes valores, podes simplesmente descartar a sessão atual usando o `session_destroy()` como é feito nos sistemas de *login* ou ainda `unset($_SESSION['indice_da_sessao'])` para desfazer uma específica.

Para usar a função `header()` enquanto uma instância de sessão ainda não foi destruída, deve-se usar o `exit()` para evitar erros, de múltiplos `headers` definidos.

---

Para armazenar configurações, informações não sensíveis, ou aquelas que não acarretam riscos para o sistema, normalmente utilizam-se `cookies`

---

## Outras referências:

[Sessões - PHP.net](http://php.net/manual/en/book.session.php)

[Cookies - PHP.net](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.cookies.php)

[Erro: Heards already sent - SOen](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8028957/how-to-fix-headers-already-sent-error-in-php)

Answer (score 1):

No seu `novaRequisicao.php`, adicione o `session_start()`:

```php
 $sql="SELECT COD_GRUPO, DES_GRUPO_PRODUTO FROM supervisor.GRUPO_PRODUTO";
$query= mssql_query($sql) or die ('Erro ao realizar consulta ao banco de dados');

if ( empty(session_id()) ) { session_start(); }
?>
```

Apartir daí, poderá utilizar a variável global de `$_SESSION`, sendo esse um *associative array*. Assim poderia usar algo como `$_SESSION['produtos']` e adicionar coisas a ele.